# Replace vector values with names

Tags: r, replace

I'm trying to replace certain temperature ranges with either "cold", "med", or "hot", and I don't know how to fix my problem. Dataset is named "stats" and temperature is "temp1".

```
tmp1<-stats$temp1
lesser<-stats[stats$temp1<=11,]
inbetween<-stats[stats$temp1>11 & stats$temp1<22,]
greater<-stats[stats$temp1>=22,]
stats$temp2<-replace(tmp1, c("lesser", "inbetween", "greater"), c("cold","med","hot"))
```

The error I keep getting is:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame replacement has 1095 rows, data has 1092

I do have several NAs, but more than 1095-1092= 3 values

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `stats` is the name of a package, so I wouldn't use that as a variable name.

Comment: But if you insist: `stats$temp2 <- ifelse(stats$temp1<=11, "cold", ifelse(stats$temp1>=22, "hot","med"))`

Comment: Maybe cut?: `stats$temp2 <- cut(stats$temp1, c(0, 11, 22, Inf), labels = c("cold","med","hot"))`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I wish I could bake you cookies!!

Comment: In StackOverflow world cookies are made of upvotes and [tickmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

@zx8754 and @N8TRO provide nice solutions (especially `cut`). Here's another one, with a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- data.frame(temp = sample(0:50, size = 30, replace = TRUE))

xy[xy$temp <= 10, "feel"] <- "cold"

xy[xy$temp > 10 & xy$temp < 30, "feel"] <- "ok"

xy[xy$temp >= 30, "feel"] <- "hothothot"

> head(xy)
  temp      feel
1    5      cold
2    2      cold
3   14        ok
4   11        ok
5   33 hothothot
6   23        ok
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could initialize `feel` with "ok" and then do two sub-assignments for `cold` and `hothothot`

Comment: @docendodiscimus true, but I wanted to do it this way to have any NAs for sanity-check in case any value is not being considered.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `cut()` and add labels as below:

```
stats$temp2 <- cut(stats$temp1, c(0, 11, 22, Inf), labels = c("cold", "med", "hot"))
```

**Note** that this resulting column is `factor`, if you need it to be a `character` then we will need to wrap it into `as.character()`.